# Wrap lines with tag using different logic in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext

I have hundreds of list items to code. each list item contains title and description in 2 lines. so what i need to do is wrap 2 lines with a tag. is there any way to do so using sublime text 2? i am using windows OS.

this is the output needed:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        this is the title
        this is the descrpition
    </li>
    <li>
        this is the title
        this is the descrpition
    </li>
</ul>
```

raw text looks like this:

this is title 
this is description 
this is title 
this is description

=====

i have tried using ctrl+shift+G and using ul>li* but unfortunately it wraps each line with `<li>`

if it is possible with sublime text, i actually need this type of structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="title">this is the title</span>
        <span class="description">this is the descrpition</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="title">this is the title</span>
        <span class="description">this is the descrpition</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show example input, expected output, and what you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: you could use notepad ++ and replace return chars with <li>

Comment: @Frank_Vr Try the idea you posted and see what you get. Is that result what the OP is asking for? I think you'll find you have missed the point pretty much completely.

Answer (score 0):

How about a two step process using find and replace?

I am assuming that:

- your original text is not indented at all;
- your indentation is two spaces; and
- you will handle the wrap with `<ul>` and resultant indentation yourself after this is done.

### Original state:

```
    this is title
    this is description
    this is title
    this is description
```

### Step one

Ensuring you have enabled regular expression matching do a find and replace using these values.

FIND WHAT :: `((.*\n){1,2})`

REPLACE WITH :: `<li>\n\1</li>\n`

Result:

```
    <li>
    this is title
    this is description
    </li>
    <li>
    this is title
    this is description
    </li>
```

### Step two

Ensuring you have enabled regular expression matching do a find and replace using these values.

FIND WHAT :: `(<li>\n)(.*)\n(.*)`

REPLACE WITH :: `\1  <span class="title">\2</span>\n  <span class="description">\3</span>`

Result:

```
    <li>
      <span class="title">this is title</span>
      <span class="description">this is description</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="title">this is title</span>
      <span class="description">this is description</span>
    </li>
```

---

What do you think?

Close enough to be useful?

Comment: I don't know what i did wrong but my output after first step looks like this [http://prntscr.com/bfrm0d]

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me. Perhaps paste the result as text as an edit to your original question maybe?

Comment: link didn't work. here is how the output was `this is title
<li>

</li>
this is description
<li>

</li>
this is title
<li>

</li>
this is description`

Comment: i got a solution to my problem. using macro on notepad++ worked for me. I recorded the code and playback to each set. thanks to all though :)

Comment: The output you got means the example text you supplied did not match the text you needed to work on. If you provide false input in your question then you must expect the answer you get to be false. How to ask for help is a vital  skill if you don't want to waste your own time and that of others.